# Why won't my placeholder show up properly? (react-native-datepicker)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having a really hard time getting a placeholder to show up properly in this datepicker package I'm using for react native...

Here's how I have the component setup:

The _onDateChange function:

```
const _onDateChange = (startTime) => {
    pickDate(props.setPatrolStartTime, startTime)
    this.setState({startTime: props.setPatrolStartTime})
}
```

The datepicker component:

```
<DatePicker
     //date={props.startTime}
     mode="datetime"
     iconComponent={ <Icon name='chevron-down' type='font-awesome' color='green'/> }
     style={ styles.datePickerStyle }
     placeholder={`Select Start Time`}
     confirmBtnText='Confirm'
     cancelBtnText='Cancel'
     customStyles={{
         dateInput:{
             borderWidth: 0,
         },
         dateText: {
             color: 'white',
             textAlign: 'left',
             fontSize: 20
         },
      }}
      onDateChange={this._onDateChange(props.startTime) }
      />
```

**Expected behavior:** I thought it would show the placeholder until I changed the date, but it would not show the placeholder until I commented out the `date` prop, and after googling and searching stackoverflow for a while, I saw various posts, some saying that I need to bind the onDateChange prop, and some requesting that I make a separate `onDateChange` function and call it from the prop.

**Actual behavior:**
I can't seem to figure out how to bind it, and when I try to call it as shown above, it red screens, saying that undefined is not a function, referencing _onDateChange. When I try to use the placeholder prop, the placeholder will not show unless I comment out the date prop, and when I do that, it shows the placeholder, except when I set the date, the placeholder doesn't change to the date I set.

At this point, I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone give me some input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `placeholderText` instead of `placeholder`

You can get reference from [here](https://reactdatepicker.com/)

Comment: Using this prop just shows the date, even when I have the date prop commented out :(

Answer (score 1):

You have used backticks instead of normal quotes, it should be

```
placeholder="Select start time"
```

You can check the example on github https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker

Comment: I used the regular quotes, without the brackets for the placeholder, but when I do this, and unless I comment out the date prop, it just shows the date instead of the placeholder... and if I do comment out the date prop, I get a warning for `possible unhandled promise rejection, evaluating this.setState` after I change the date, and the placeholder does not change to the date.

Answer (score 0):

`placeholder` does *not* take an **object**, however, it takes a **string** like this:
 `placeholder="select date"`
not like this:
`placeholder={"select date"}`
also, the placeholder value only shows up when this.props.date is false

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in the library, and it hasn't been updated in a year. If you want to prevent the current date from showing up by using a placeholder, **you will need to set `placeholder` to be a non-empty string and it should work.**

The input value still needs to be falsy for the placeholder to appear (e.g. an empty string as date/time).

Answer (score 0):

Update 2022,

there still is a bug trying to display a placeholder, the work around I found is to use the `customInput` to return a `div` and use the `::after` CSS pseudoelement to insert whatever text you like